# What does MVC3 do with C# Optional Parameters?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

Setup the following Controller

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    // GET: /Home/Read    
    public string Read(Sample sample = null)
    {
        if (sample != null)
            Console.WriteLine("Not null");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("null");

        return "";
    }

}
public class Sample
{

}
```

Sample is **not null**.  Is this a bug or a feature?

Comment: What IS Sample...and how are you invoking your GET request (what url)?

Comment: Also, it should be noted that optional parameters are a compile time, not runtime feature. There is no runtime difference between a method with optional parameters vs without optional parameters. Since MVC3's controller mechanism is based on reflection at runtime, the only way it would know about optional parameters is if it's looking for the OptionalAttribute on the ParameterInfo....

Comment: @JeffN825 in this case Sample is defined exactly as written in the OP.  Get request http://server/Home/Read as defined in code comment above.

Comment: I believe you would need to define your MVC route for this controller as having the route parameter be optional if you want MVC to recognize it as such.

Comment: For future SO folks, I realized the parameter name matters to the router.  By default the router looks for just `id`.  I named my parameter `sample`.  So when I visit my page `/Home/Read/whatever`, the parameter comes in as `id` not `sample`.  This caused a lot of confusion.  I believe this is what @JeffN825 was trying to get at.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Optional parameters are implemented  via *call-site rewriting*. Since the controller will be invoked using a full parameter list by the MVC engine, the optional parameter is simply not relevant.

For example, given the following function:

```
public void Foo(int bar = 1, int baz = 2)
{
}
```

Calling it like so:

```
Foo();
```

Causes the compiler to actually interpret it as:

```
Foo(1, 2);
```

There is no magic that occurs whereby the call remains as `Foo()`, and then the method itself subs in the parameters at run-time. The parameters are subbed in at compile-time, and nothing futher needs to be done.

**Update**: To indicate to MVC that a given route parameter is optional, you can set it to `UrlParameter.Optional` when defining your route. At that point, the default parameter value of the action method should kick in.

Comment: What you posted here makes sense.  But, I don't know how to relate this to NULL params.  Shouldn't that mean Foo() becomes Foo(null)?  If so, I'm still unsure how this answers my question...to me this just makes it more concrete.  What am I missing?

Comment: This answer is not really relevant to the question directly. The relevant point is that the only way MVC would know the parameter is optional is if upon reflection, it checks if the ParameterInfo has an OptionalAttribute...

Comment: Sorry, I should have highlighted that portion. Basically, the MVC engine will call your controller method with a full parameter set by default, so the fact one of the parameters is optional doesn't matter. I believe you can define certain route parameters as optional; would need to look it up.

Comment: Yes, I agree that would be the solution - to define the controller's route with an optional parameter.

Comment: I sort-a understand what is going on now.  The UrlParameter.Optional deal is not changing the object to null.  I am probably doing something wrong in the router as I don't have good knowledge on routing. At least I know its not a bug.

Answer (score 1):

Its a feature not a bug. The binder sees that method signature is the only one that makes sense (if you define one with no parameter I'd imagine that would be called instead or you would get the 'ambiguous call' error) and creates an empty instance since there are no query string parameters available. Since its the model binder doing the magic of creating your instance and not the compiler here, it's MVC's doing.