# MVC3 Optional parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, optional-parameters, method-signature

This is a follow up to this:
[What does MVC3 do with C# Optional Parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7244887/what-does-mvc3-do-with-c-sharp-optional-parameters)

I have an action with the following signature:

```
public ViewResult Show(int Id, PublishingErrorSummary pubErrors=null, String title=null)
```

On requesting server/show/1 pubErrors is not null, but title is null. How is it possible? These are just two objects but string somehow manages to become null. Where can I fix this?

Edit: class definition added

```
public class PublishingErrorSummary
{
    public List<string> StepOneErrors { get; set; }
    public List<string> StepTwoErrors { get; set; }
    public List<string> StepThreeErrors { get; set; }
    public List<string> StepFourErrors { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`PublishingErrorSummary` is a complex object. The default model binder always initializes complex objects. It doesn't really make sense to set its default value to null. Same stands for the title parameter. Strings are reference types and their default value will be null anyway if no request parameter `title` is sent.

Comment: Thanks for such a quick response!
"The default model binder will initialize it if in the request it encounters a key that corresponds to one of the properties of this model"
It does make sense, but there's no keys that would correspond to any of the properties of PublishingErrorSummary. I'm adding defintion of  the class just now. Does it mean that complex types always get instantiated by the default binder? My routes are typical with only ID being Optional and others are not mentioned in routes.

Comment: @Mariusz.W, you are correct. The default model binder will always instantiate the complex object even if there are no parameters in the request matching the properties of this model. I have updated my answer.

Comment: thanks! Will check if all lists are null :D Not in mood for custom binder today!